# Filtering JSON array of Dates based on Transformed Logic in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I have some JSON that has an array of objects. One of the items in the objects is a timestamp that I would like to filter based on user selection.

Basically a user selects a date from a dropdown on the frontend, then I would like to filter the array based on if the date is between their selected date minus 7 days (no time element involved from user, just whole day).

For brevity sake lets assume the user sends in "2022-03-02" as their selection from the button (I have this part already figured out so I made up some basic stuff to simulate this interaction). Based on the example JSON I provided, the expected behavior would be to remove the last 2 objects from `jsonData.features` array.

The main question I am trying to understand is how to filter this array after I have to do some `Date` manipulation (e.g. I am transforming the raw json array but still want to filter out data based on this transformation logic). I am pretty new to working with JS dates so any advice in regards to that end would be appreciated as well. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fixed a Syntax issue.

Sample of what the JSON looks like

```
var jsonData = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
       "features": [
          {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-02T12:01:02.001Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-80.71, 28.34]}},
          {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-02T12:03:01.46Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-79.89, 28.45]}},
          {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-02T12:07:02.21Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-60.79, 28.32]}},
          {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-05T14:10:02.61Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-60.79, 28.32]}},
          {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-09T17:12:02.14Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-60.79, 28.32]}}
       ]};
```

So essentially this is how it looks in JS.

```
// assume user selects date and clicks button
var dateNode = "2022-03-02"; // example user input as a date string

// function to move backwards n days from date
function datePrior(date, daysPrior) {
    let tmp = new Date(date.getTime());
    tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate() - daysPrior); // subtract n days from the date
    return tmp.getTime();
}

function main() {
     const selectedDate = new Date(dateNode); // convert user string date to actual Date
     const selectedDateWeekPrior = datePrior(selectedDate, 7); // subtract one week from the date

     if (jsonData){
         // filter array based on date
         let filteredArray = jsonData.features.filter(item => {
                             return Date(item.properties.time_stamp).getTime() >= selectedDateWeekPrior && Date(item.properties.time_stamp).getTime() <= selectedDate.getTime();
                            });
    };
};
main();
```

Comment: At first, I misread the question, though I'm having difficulty understanding what is the problem with your proposed solution or what is exactly the question.

Do you want to modify the dates, and still keep the `jsonData` filtered?

Comment: @c6p End goal is filtering the array. I only want to keep dates that are within the user's date minus 7 days. To create those bounds, I need to perform some logic on the timestamp which requires transformation of the date fields to subtract 7 days. I want the original array filtered based on that logic.

Comment: Your second comparison `item.properties.time_stamp <= selectedDate.getTime()` is missing a conversion to milliseconds. Though I think what you are currently doing is correct. Convert everything to epoch, then compare them.

Comment: @c6p I made my JSON needlessly nested. I'll revert it to something simpler to make the question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
<script>
    var jsonData = [{"type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-02T12:01:02.001Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-80.71, 28.34]}},
            {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-02T12:03:01.46Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-79.89, 28.45]}},
            {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-02T12:07:02.21Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-60.79, 28.32]}},
            {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-08T14:10:02.61Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-60.79, 28.32]}},
            {"type": 'Feature', "properties": {"time_stamp": "2022-03-09T17:12:02.14Z"}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-60.79, 28.32]}}
        ]}
    ]
    var dateNode = "2022-03-15"
    var toDate = new Date(dateNode);
    var dateNode7Days = new Date(toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()-7))
  
    let filteredArray = jsonData[0].features.filter(item => (new Date(item.properties.time_stamp).setHours(0,0,0,0) <= new Date(dateNode).setHours(0,0,0,0)) && new Date(item.properties.time_stamp).setHours(0,0,0,0) >= dateNode7Days.setHours(0,0,0,0) );
    console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: This is good, but how do I take into account the subtraction of 7 days from the ```dateNode```. That is where I am doing the transformation in my question and which causes issues.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: This is great logic, thanks. However, I'm not getting expected results. I fear it may have to do with some time zone stuff. When using "2022-03-02" I would expect to find the first 3 objects in the ```jsonData.features``` array. However, it returns an empty array. when using your example with "2022-03-15" I do get one result back which is the last item in the ```jsonData.features``` array. It seems to be working but there might be some slight tweaks due to time zone issues? not sure. I am testing it more.